# javascript: MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, spotify

I am trying to make a simple get authorization request to the Spotify Api. If i make a GET HTTPRequest then i get a cross-domain error. Hence I making a JSONP request using a callback, but this leads to a MIME type error as shown above, whose workaround i have found is to again make an HTTPRequest JSON request to match the MIME type. Quite a deadlock I am in here ! Please help! Thanks

This is my js code block:

```
(function(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://samcasm.github.io/moodsetNow/moodset.html&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=34fFs29kd09?callback=mySpotify';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
})();

function mySpotify(){
console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: @J F here u go @JF

Comment: @J F that's right I am trying to load an authorization html file as a response from the Api. The request works fine on POSTMAN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you’re using a `<script>` tag to load something that’s an HTML page. This is my suggested solution:

1. When the user needs to authenticate, redirect them:

   ```
   location.href = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize" + 
       "?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID +
       "&response_type=token" + 
       "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(THE_URI_TO_REDIRECT_TO) + 
       "&state=" + STATE + // optional
       "&scope=" + SCOPES.join(" ") + // optional
       "";
   ```

   Note that if you’re going to redirect on page load, use `location.replace(...)` instead of `location.href = ...`. This way, the user will not have the immediately-redirecting page in their back button history.
2. Then, at the URL in `THE_URI_TO_REDIRECT_TO`, parse the hash:
   Spotify makes a hash like this: `#access_token=...&expiry=...`. `location.hash` returns that hash, including the leading `#`. First, we set up our object that will hold the options:

   ```
   var hash = {};
   ```

   then, we remove the `#`:

   ```
   var h = location.hash.slice(1)
   ```

   … and split on the `&`s.

   ```
   h = h.split('&')
   ```

   Next, we iterate over all of the pairs (`forEach`) and put the two pieces in the `hash` object (i. e. `hash['access_token'] = '...';`

   ```
   h.forEach(function(pair) {
       pair = pair.split('=');
       hash[pair.shift()] = pair.join('=');
   });
   ```
3. After that, you can read the data.

   ```
   if (hash.error) {
       console.log(hash.error);
   } else {
       var token = hash.access_token;
       hash.token_type === "Bearer";
       var expiry = new Date();
       expiry.setSeconds(expiry.getSeconds() + (+hash.expires_in));
   }
   var state = hash.state; // optional
   ```

Comment: @J F couldn't thank you enough! Just one thing, could you tell me what you did there in the callback script (point 2), or maybe point me to a direction so i can learn more about it. I have been working with Apis lately and haven't yet figured clearly how the redirect uri works or what the script does. Thanks again :D!

Comment: @J F awesome! That makes complete sense ! Thanks a ton ! Cheers ^_^

Comment: Hey @J F just one thing, if the hash function(named myfunction() ) is embedded in a script tag of my same index.html which is being called in the redirect_uri , would this call    https://my.github.acc/reponame/index.html?callback=myfunction   invoke it ?

Comment: No. That’s just JSONP. However, you could put a `?login` or something in the `redirect_uri` that you check for and then call `myfunction()`. It’s probably easier to have separate pages, though.